# Split tool is deleting segment at split point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, features, delete, splitting

I turned editing on and selected this line feature from a feature class. After I selected this line feature, I clicked the Split Tool to separate the line at the vertex (the corner). When I click at the vertex, or any other point on the line, a portion of the line is simply disappearing instead of becoming two separate features. Any ideas on why this is happening?

[image: Split tool is deleting segment at split point]

Comment: So it turns out that the line feature was divided into two segments like it was supposed to, however one of the new portions is invisible?

Answer (score 4):

I was editing a layer, the layer was a reference of another feature class. So to answer. It wasn't deleting; I don't understand why the line segment was disappearing, but because the edits I was making to the layer were being made to the real feature class (line), I suppose this had something to do with it.

Moral: DO NOT make edits to a layer you created from some selected features. EITHER edit the original feature class objects OR export the layer you created from selected features BEFORE you attempt to make any edits.

Comment: That makes sense - if it was a layer created from a selection in another layer, your new feature (due to the splitting one line into two) won't have been in that selection set so wasn't visible.  If you load your original feature class the edit will be visible.

Comment: This is the same thing that happens when you edit a layer that has a definition query.  New features will disappear after you create them because they are not included in the definition query.